# only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars-OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am getting an error trying to morph(ish??) image.The main purpose of this algorithm is to find lanes in a given road.But I am getting an error that says  only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars on OpenCV. Here is my code:

```
enter code here 
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv

def canny(image):
gray=cv.cvtColor(lane_image,cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blur=cv.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
canny_image=cv.Canny(blur,50,150)
return canny_image

def display_lines(image,lines):
    line_image=np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            x1,y1,x2,y2=line.reshape(4)
            cv.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),10)
    return line_image 

def region_of_interest(image):
    height=image.shape[0]
    polygons=np.array([[(200,height),(735,height),(445,250)]])
    mask=np.zeros_like(image)
    cv.fillPoly(mask,polygons,255)
    masked_image=cv.bitwise_and(image, mask)
    return masked_image



image=cv.imread("D:/large_thumbnail.jpg")

lane_image=np.copy(image)

canny=canny(lane_image)
cropped_image=region_of_interest(canny)
lines=cv.HoughLinesP(cropped_image,2,np.pi/180,100,np.array([]),minLineLength=40,maxLineGap=5)

line_im=display_lines(lane_image,lines)

combo_add=cv.addWeighted(lane_image,0,8,line_im,1,1)---> the error line 

cv.imshow("",combo_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv.addWeighted` expects the third argument to be `src2`. You have passed `line_im` as the fourth argument. The fourth argument is expected to be a scalar value, whereas you are passing a `numpy.ndarray`. Change your call as below:

```
combo_add=cv.addWeighted(lane_image,8,line_im,1,1)
```